# variable not initializing despite the fact that it is identical to other variables that work

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I am very new to coding in general as well as this site so any help is appreciated!

This short code i made will not run because the variable str will not initialize.
It seems identical to several other variables that run as expected.

My question is why is this happening as well as how do i fix it.

Here is the code

```
package firstgameattempt1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateChar {
    public static void main (String Args[]){

        System.out.println( "please enter your Characters name");
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in); 
        String Cname = in.next();
        System.out.println("so your name is ");
        System.out.println(Cname);
        System.out.println("thats the dumbest thing ive ever heard");

        int str;
        int intelligence;
        int speed;
        int hp;
        int maxhp;

        System.out.println("enter 1 if you are a warrior, 2 if you are a mage, or 3 if you are a thief ");
        int Cclass = in.nextInt();
        if (Cclass == 1 ) 
            str = 10;
        intelligence = 5;
        speed = 7;
        hp= 100;
        maxhp = 100;
        System.out.println ("your strength is");

        //here is the problem
        System.out.println (str);
        //here is the problem

        System.out.println ("your intelligence is");
        System.out.println (intelligence);
        System.out.println ("your speed is");
        System.out.println (speed);
        System.out.println ("you have ");
        System.out.println (hp);    
        System.out.println ("hitpoints");
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, I am using Java.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is occurring becuase

`int str;`

is not initialized when it is created (such as setting it = 0).

You do have code setting the value to `10` but that happens only if the condition of your `if(Cclass==1)` statement is `true`, so if that statement is `false`, `str` would remain uninitialized. Make sure that it always has a value regardless of if `Cclass == 1` or not.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I have a follow up question if I may. Why does this issue not affect any of the subsequent variables?

Comment: I am thinking what you meant to do was only have all those variables set if `Cclass == 1`. There are two ways you can use an `if` statement. The first way is as a one liner where only the following line is run when the statement is true, and the other way is with a block like this `if(true){ // do some things }` so you are not getting the error with the others because the lines that set those values are being run because Java thinks you only wanted `str` set as a result of the `if` condition. This page has more details https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: Thanks again Carl!

Answer (score 0):

From your indentation I assume you want all the assignments to be a part of the if statement. Put it inside a block, like so:

```
if (Cclass == 1 ) {
        str = 10;
        intelligence = 5;
        speed = 7;
        hp= 100;
        maxhp = 100;
}
```

You will, however, still get the warning that the variables may not have been initialized, which is correct. Look at the code. You are using (printing) the variables no matter what has happened before, but the initialization is conditioned. You could do something like this:

```
if (Cclass == 1 ) {
        str = 10;
        ...
} else { 
    str = 0;
    ...
}
```

Another way is to initialize them before:

```
int str = 0;
...
if (Cclass == 1 ) {
        str = 10;
        ...
}
```

Maybe none of these are suitable for your case, but the point is is that Java does not allow usage of an uninitialized variable, and this is checked at compile time.

I don't know if you have tried coding Python, but your mistake is very typical for Python code. In Java, indentation does nothing for the syntax. In Python you use indentation to specify blocks. In Java and many other languages, you use { } instead.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer!